# Difference between typical Windows and .NET binaries

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

What is the difference between typical Windows (WIn32? COM? Not sure what they are called.) DLLs and the DLLs that are compiled using .NET?

I know they are different, but I do not know the inner workings in detail.

I would love to know what the exact difference is.

**EDIT: Trying to add more of my doubts here:**

Why is it that I cannot add a reference to a Win32 DLL like I would add a reference for a .NET DLL? Also, why do we have to do a PInvoke? How do we have reflection and intellisense for .NET DLLs but not something similar for Win32 dlls?

Comment: The "starting point" is the [PE header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). Recent windows versions have special support for CLR so it knows how to load the IL. Then from there... where would you like to go? :)

Comment: Yes please. More of this. Also, why is it that I can add a reference to a .NET DLL but not a WIn32 DLL. Also, why do we have to do a PInvoke, also how we have reflection and intellisense for .NET DLLs but not something similar for Win32 dlls. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Reflection for the .NET DLL's would be possible because the .NET runtime can give information on the code (kind of like a virtual machine).

Comment: Look up the difference between "managed" and "unmanaged" code. This question is hopelessly broad.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is way too broad to be answered fully, so I'll focus only on your first doubt.

**A .NET binary *is* a "typical" Windows binary.**

A .NET PE is a PE just like the others. It has an MZ header, a DOS segment, a PE header, a section table and sections: `.text`, `.reloc`, `.rsrc`. So far, everything is normal. A "typical" Windows binary contains all of these things, only the sections vary , depending on the compiler and language.

The `.text` table contains an import table that imports one single DLL, `mscoree.dll`, and one single function, `_CorExeMain`. It also contains the .NET section: data about how your program works (classes, methods, etc), metadata and IL.

So what happens when you start a .NET binary? Nothing really fancy. It simply works just like a "typical" Windows binary. It calls upon `mscoree.dll` to create a .NET runtime, that will load the .NET section of your executable. That runtime knows how to execute IL.

Comment: While your answer is correct, it has nothing to do with the question - since .Net binaries are not compiled the same as .Net DLL's which are not native\backward compatible (like .Net binaries)

Comment: @user4537: It looks like I misunderstood the question. However .NET DLLs behave like the executables, the difference being that the import is `_CorDllMain` instead of `_CorExeMain`.

Comment: @user4537 .NET DLL's are certainly native AND backwards compatible.